# How To Use InAppWebView in flutter for Older SDK

Tags: android, flutter

So, I wanted to implement InAppWebView in my application, but it forces me to change the SDK version to 33. However, I want the application to be compatible with older Android versions as well. It doesn't compile/save any results until I change the Android SDK version to 33 and use an SDK 33 virtual device.

Comment: See the difference between `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element